# Python mfc100u.dll error with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I have made a python file and I want to convert it to an MSI file. Here is my code:

```
from cx_Freeze import *

includefiles=[]
excludes=[]
packages=["tkinter", "openpyxl"]
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

shortcut_table = []

company_name = 'Bills Programs'
product_name = 'BananaCell'

msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table}

bdist_msi_options = { 'upgrade_code': '{Banana-rama-30403344939493}', 
'add_to_path': False, 'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % 
(company_name, product_name), }

setup(
     version = "0.1",
     description = "Lightweight excel comparing program",
     author = "Bill",
     name = "BananaCell",
     options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}, "bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options,},
     executables = [
        Executable(
        script="comparing.py",
        base=base,
        shortcutName="BananaCell",
        shortcutDir="DesktopFolder",
        icon='icon.ico',
        )
    ]
 )
```

But when I run the following code, the installation completes but I get the following error [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mTAe.png)

What am I doing wrong? I have full access ti the directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the `.py` file from the terminal with admin privileges? You can do that by running `Powershell` *as an Administrator*

Comment: @SreetamDas yes I have tried and it does not work